# what are the methods to check if my model fits the data (without using graphs)

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, classification, logistic-regression

I am working on a binary logistic regression data set in python. I want to know if there are any numerical methods to calculate how well the model fits the data.
please don't include graphical methods like plotting etc.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

read through 3.3.2. Classification metrics in sklearn documentation.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html

hope it helps.